# What's a good sports tracker app for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, gps, time-tracking

I'm looking for an app for tracking activities like **walking, running or bicycling**. Lots of people I know with Android or Nokia phones use such apps, but I don't know what's a good option for iOS.

Requirements:

- Can track **time** & **distance** covered (using GPS)
- Should be very simple to use: 1) start the tracker 2) go for the walk/run/ride 3) stop the tracker and see the distance & time
- Available on App Store (i.e. works on non-jailbroken devices)

**Preferably free**, but feel free to recommend an excellent paid app too if you know of one.

Also, it's a plus if I can use the app for my simple needs **without signing up** to any service.

Comment: Oh, and integration with [HeiaHeia!](http://www.heiaheia.com/) would be a huge plus.

Comment: You might find some good advice for this over on [Fitness & Nutrition](http://fitness.stackexchange.com) as well. [Here's a link](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/5796/1499) to an answer I gave about good workout apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently switch from RunKeeper to RunMeter. RunMeter provides a [comparison chart](http://www.abvio.com/running-guide/) for RunMeter, Nike +, RunKeeper and iMapMyRun+.

Might give you a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, the comparison chart is very useful (even though it's designed to plug their product)! I think I'll give RunMeter a go... I appreciate the fact it doesn't require login to companion site.

Comment: Having just tried it for a run, RunMeter is exactly what I needed! It has a rich feature set (e.g. GPX export for HeiaHeia) but that doesn't get in the way: the basic functionality is still very simple to use. Plus the app doesn't require any kind of registration. It cost me **0.79 €**, and is totally worth it.

Comment: Glad that my recommendation works for you

Comment: I would like to add that RunMeter seems to be the best option for someone that wants all of their data and not to be integrated into a web app. Nike+ seems far, far better than it was this time last year and their Fuel Band is nice, but for iOS data collection, my recommendation would still be RunMeter.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of them in the App Store that meet your criteria.  Here are the ones I've used:

1. **Strava**.  This app motivates people into exercising harder by bringing out their competitive side.  With Strava, you can compare your times with others who've done the same route.  This app is most useful when you workout in a group where you'll be able to push each other.
2. **Runkeeper**.  The unique feature of this app is in its "coaching".  Basically, if you like to change your pace at certain intervals, the app can notify you when to switch.  Additionally, this app can pair to a heartrate monitor.
3. **MapMyRun**.  This one tries to be your overall fitness app where you can also log your caloric intake and other activities such as weightlifting.

They are all good options depending on your specific needs.  Try them all and see one fits you best.  Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Sports Tracker](http://www.sports-tracker.com) for the last two years. Its interface is IMHO better than any other interface I have seen and its integration to the web site is rock solid.  I have used Strava, Endomondo, Runkeeper, and Mapmyride (which would also be awesome except for the live tracking bugs.

Here's what you get from the website:

[image]
[image]

And the phone app is very similiar (but skinnied down).  Here is what I really like: on the data view tab if you click on "Lap Info", you get everything broken down into the splits; the cool part is when you mouse over each segment it shows you on the map.

Here is what it is missing: Live Tracking, which is being talked about on their forums and is a coming feature.

Here is what it does have:  Route Time/Speed comparisons, it has HRM functionality (I don't use that part so I won't speak about it, it posts to Facebook with ease (and Twitter).  Its GPS doesn't freak out, it isn't a batter hog.  Completely free.

I am more than glad to provide more information if you send me an email or post here.

Comment: You mention the iPhone app and what it shows. You may consider posting a screenshot (hold down the home and power button and the screenshot will show up in your photos)

Answer (score 1):

I use [**Xtrail**.app](http://sophiestication.com/xtrail/) a lot theses days.

It's made by a well known iOs and Mac os x app Developer,
it has all the requirement you need:

> Can track time & distance covered (using GPS)

Check all of that + a lot more informations,
i use it for bicycling, so it's in my pocket and the GPS is really fine

> Should be very simple to use: 1) start the tracker 2) go for the walk/run/ride 3) stop the tracker and see the distance & time

Super simple to use, you switch on button and lets go, when you have finish
switch the button again and you're asked if you have stopped, the you have the result.

> Available on App Store (i.e. works on non-jailbroken devices)

It's work fine on my iPhones and iPad + it's has iCloud syncing of everthing.

There is one things left, it's not free but as a Apple Dev i like to pay for well-done
apps, and this one is perfect, so i don't bother giving some $$ to people doing
this for a living.

Oh and of course don't forget to check their website: http://sophiestication.com/xtrail/